# rxjs - [ts] Type 'Observable<{} | T>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<T>'

Tags: rxjs, observable, rxjs5

```
    public get<T>(url: string, httpParams: Array<Map<string, string>>): Observable<T> {
    return this.httpClient
        .get<T>(url, { params: this.appendHttpParams(httpParams), headers: this.httpHeaders })
        .catch((error, some): any => {
            console.log(error);
        });

}
```

I have this wrapper function around my http service in Angular 4. It works fine without the return type specified. However, if I provide the same return type of the 'httpClient.get()' which is Observable, it throws an error

> [ts] Type 'Observable<{} | T>' is not assignable to type
>   'Observable'. Type '{} | T' is not assignable to type 'T'.     Type
>   '{}' is not assignable to type 'T'.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use `do` and not `catch`.  `catch` is intended for scenarios where you want to handle the error and continue the observable chain.  In a `catch` method you are supposed to return a different observable that the chain can switch to.  For example:

```
this.httpClient
    .get<T>(...)
    .catch(err => {
        return this.cachedVersion;
    );
```

Anyways, since you don't have any return statement in your `catch` method it is returning void.  That is why your observable changes to `Observable<T|{}>` because it will be a chain that emits `T` if there is no error and `{}` if there is an error.